# Why form tag is required to delete data in laravel 5 ?

Tags: php, laravel-5, crud

In Laravel 4, the data in the list can be deleted without using `<form>` tag. But, in laravel 5, it says we need `form` tag with action to delete the data . What's the reason ??

Comment: where this been said? I still can delete data without form in laravel 5.2.

Comment: so you must be using method_field righ t?

Comment: no, with Eloquent I can delete as much as I want at any time.

Comment: It depends on your route, if the route (for deleting) declared using `GET` method then you should be able to delete the record without any form.

Answer (score 0):

Because laravel got the method_field(method) function to emulate DELETE, PUT, PATCH method.
It will create an hidden input which give the method name to laravel when the request arrives into the application.

Documentation words : "hidden input field containing the spoofed value of the form's HTTP verb." [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers)

```
{!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
```

Resource controller expect all method_field. To get data it's by default GET method, to save it's POST method, to update it should be PUT or PATCH and to delete DELETE field is required by the application.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers
Check out the resource routing method field list

Comment: method_field method is used to **generates an HTML hidden input field containing the spoofed value of the form's HTTP verb.** But, the thing which can be done without the form tag why to use that method ??

Comment: It's a proper way to process your form, you can add a csrf field for security purpose "csrf_field()" and if you're using resource routing. As you may know, to process data you should use a form. Do you have any error message or just a satus code of your request ?

Comment: I don't know any screenshot or error message/code ? teamviewer ? or edit your post with some code. We're blind to see any problems here ..

Comment: Actually, in laravel 4 you don't required any kind of method to delete data and same for to edit and view. But in laravel 5, we require method_field to delete data . I just want to know reason behind it .

Comment: Tell me which types of routing your using. As I SAID, I can't answer you without minimum of codes. If you're using a resource that's normal. It except DELETE method_field to process a suppression that's all and edit should have this too. If you won't add this field just make your route linked to your method's controller with Route::post('url', 'controller@method');

Comment: So, do you mean if we use resourceful route then we need method_field to delete data but when we link our route to methods controller then it will not required method_field/form tag ?

Comment: Exactly. Resource controller expect all method_field. To get data it's by default GET method, to save it's POST method, to update it should be PUT or PATCH and to delete DELETE field is required by the application. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers check out le resource routing method field list

Comment: so, we don't need method_field if we don't use Restful Route??

Comment: exactly resource routing is for RESTful services.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is RESTful framework, A restful controller follows the standard blueprint for a restful resource (GET,POST,PUT/PATCH and DELETE), if you want to add delete button in your app this handy javascript code can help you for your all delete buttons code written by great jeffery way

https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/5112282

branches for laravel 5

https://gist.github.com/soufianeEL/3f8483f0f3dc9e3ec5d9

https://gist.github.com/ghprod/0bb7f8d207ba7838a0e6

Comment: What if i don't want to use RESTful route ? I just want an explanation  why the laravel changes these things in laravel 5 . As in laravel 4 we don't need these things ??

Comment: in that case you have to write route for each delete call for each controller right now you are calling route Route::resource('page','PageController') and you have full CURD with resource, custom route will be Route::get('delete/{id}','PageController@deletePage')